# What was Zangetsu's Task for Ichigo to get Bankai?

Tags: bleach

When Ichigo is about to start his training to obtain Bankai, Zangetsu fills the area with different swords and tells Ichigo that only one is his true self and all other would break indicating that Zangetsu wanted Ichigo to find his true form and defeat him with it.

During the training Ichigo is just grabbing swords at random, at one point after being pushed back he just grabs another without looking. Yoruichi also comments on how at the beginning any sword Ichigo took broke after receiving a single attack but now they seem to last longer almost indicating that Ichigo was not meant to be finding Zangetsu's true form but instead get stronger using the fakes, also Yoruichi must have been able to hear Zangetsu's explanation to Ichigo because of how he was summoned (unlike before when Ichigo lost to Kenpachi)

So i am wondering, What was Zangetsu's Task for Ichigo to get Bankai? was it to defeat him with his true form or something else.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to ask here... are you looking to find out what role Zangetsu plays in Ichigo's Bankai training?

Comment: @Krazer More of less, at first it seems like Zangetsu is indicating his wants Ichigo to find his true self but Ichigo's actions and Yoruichi's Comments contradict this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mentioned that this method only worked once before. Hence, it is a tested but not used method. As for the training, the user was supposed to fight the personification of the Zanpakto, or Zangetsu for Ichigo, since for the Bankai one needs the 'materialization and submission of the Soul Cutter'.

[image: start]

It was mentioned beforehand that the sword around represent the weakness in his heart and with each broken sword he will get stronger. However, he has to survive the complete training first.

[image: training]